# empty dataTable gird is being shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have written a small sample program to bind JSON data in a grid using Datatable

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>
<body>

 <table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr><th class="site_name">symbol</th><th>qunatity </th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){

 var r =  [
 {"symbol":"BPCL","qunatity":"1222"},{"symbol":"HDCF","qunatity":"2333"}
 ]

$("##example").dataTable({
    "aaData":r,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
    "aoColumns": [
      { "mData": "symbol" },
      { "mData": "qunatity" }

    ],
  });


  })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i ran this program except the header , no data is being displayed , could you please let me know what might the cause for it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `#` in `$("##example").dataTable({`

Comment: Thank you very much that worked with your change , i have one more question , how ca i apply sorting on each of the field ?? is that possible

Comment: Yes, it is - you'll find samples in the dataTable documentation, if I recall correctly.